# Python: Sharding cookies?

Tags: javascript, python, http

I want to send data about the currently being served page from server to client, but do not want to put it in the HTML because the data will only be ready after the entire page is rendered. I could easily append it after the closing `</html>` tag, and browsers generally render it correctly, but it seems messy and violates the HTML spec. If I wanted to put it somewhere valid, I would have to do some regex digging into the already generated text-html-blob, which I don't really want to do.

I have been sending the data in cookies, but once the data grows (more than 4KB) the cookies just disappear silently. I'm considering sharding the data into multiple cookies and unsharding them when they are sent back from the server to extract the original content, but it seems to me like there should be a better way of doing this.

Perhaps chunking the http response to dump the (rather large) amount of data in a secondary transfer, or stuffing it all into the headers? Or even maintaining session and have the javascript send an Ajax request back to the ser I'm not sure how feasible this would be, but i really do want to find a way to send somewhat large amounts of data to the client, without doing any

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't want to include it as part of the html? You can wrap it in comment <!-- --> tags if you want to hide it from being rendered to the screen

Comment: Looks like a strange architecture. What are these data about? Why are they available only at the end of the request? If it's some knd of meta-data, I think a proper way to pass it along is custom HTTP headers in the response. But again, why are these data so big?